# SQL Group by but record relationship

Tags: sql, string, group-by, azure-sql-database, window-functions

Here is my question:

I have the following data that I am looking to de-dupe and generally clean, the fields are:

- UniqueID
- Name
- PhoneNumber
- Email

RDBMS is Azure SQL

What I'm wanting to do is to do a Group-By on Name, Phone Number and Email and then record the UniqueID in a separate column e.g.:

```
NewUniqueID Name PhoneNumber Email OldIDs
1 Sam Smith 091234567 sam.smith@test.com 12,54,65,70
```

However, I'm not sure what the correct terminology is to create the OldIDs field, so I've been unable to find out how to do it.

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data.  How are the rows that should be combined together identified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *seem* to want string aggregation:

```
select 
    row_number() over(order by (select null)) newUniqueID,
    name,
    phoneNumber,
    email,
    string_agg(uniqueID, ',') oldIDs
from mytable
group by name, phoneNumber, email
```

This generates one row per `(name, phoneNumber, email)` tuple, and concatenate all `uniqueID`s in column `oldIDs`. `row_number()` assigns a new `id` to each row in the resultset.

Comment: Perfect! You've saved me a lot of pain and anguish!